# unable to start cronservice as www-data user

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am trying to start cron-service using www-data user in Docker, it says Starting periodic command scheduler: cronseteuid: Operation not permitted
failed!

Below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2.12-fpm@sha256:2aa938b6d62f7415e9c84d867d9ceed18ef8ec3cf3944d389e088c93f9678a84 as base 

# Set environment variables
ENV DOC_ROOT /var/www/html
ENV COMPOSER_HOME=/tmp/composer

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gnupg \
    netcat-openbsd \
    supervisor \
    openssl \
    nginx \
    wget \
    telnet \
    traceroute \
    net-tools \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    libicu-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libsodium-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    rsync \
    unzip \
    cron \
    default-mysql-client \
    git \
    gnupg \
    gzip \
    libbz2-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libsodium-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    lsof \
    mailutils \
    msmtp \
    procps \
    vim \
    zip \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install APCu and other PHP extensions
RUN pecl install apcu-5.1.22 \
    && docker-php-ext-configure \
        gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        bz2 \
        calendar \
        exif \
        gd \
        gettext \
        intl \
        mbstring \
        mysqli \
        opcache \
        pcntl \
        pdo_mysql \
        soap \
        sockets \
        sodium \
        sysvmsg \
        sysvsem \
        sysvshm \
        xsl \
        zip 

# Create necessary directories and set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /var/run \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/run \
    && mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/{body,fastcgi} \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx \
    && touch /var/run/crond.pid \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/run/crond.pid \
    && touch /run/nginx.pid \
    && chown www-data:www-data /run/nginx.pid \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx/error.log \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx/access.log

# Copy cronjob configuration and set permissions
COPY  magento /etc/cron.d/cronjob
RUN chown www-data:www-data /etc/cron.d/cronjob \
    && chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronjob

# Set up cron logging
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/cron.log 

# Set root password
RUN echo 'root:Login#22' | chpasswd

# Install Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Set PHP configuration
RUN echo "memory_limit=1G" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-memory-limit-php.ini \
    && echo "apc.enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-apcu.ini \
    && echo "apc.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-apcu.ini \
    && echo "opcache.memory_consumption=512MB" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf \
    && echo "opcache.max_accelerated_files=60000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf \
    && echo "opcache.consistency_checks=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf \
    && echo "opcache.validate_timestamps=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf \
    && echo "opcache.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf


FROM base as build

# Install and configure supervisord
COPY etc/nginx /etc/nginx
COPY etc/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/supervisor

# Switch to www-data user
USER www-data
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy Magento application files and entrypoint script
COPY --from=composer:2.2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY --chown=www-data magentoapps/magento .
COPY --chown=www-data bin bin 
COPY bin/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint

# Create temporary directory
RUN mkdir /tmp/app

# Install dependencies and set up Magento application
RUN composer install \
    && bin/magento sampledata:deploy \
    && bin/magento module:enable --all \
    && cp -r app /tmp/app 

# Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Set Magento mode to developer
ENV MAGE_MODE=developer
```

below is the supervisorfile

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock
chmod=0700

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=www-data
loglevel=info
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0
redirect_stderr=true

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0



[program:cron]
command=/usr/sbin/cron -f
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

Tried manually running the command it failed, but with root its running

Tried to set all the permission for /usr/sbin/cron.d

Tried manually running the command it failed, but with root its running

Tried to set all the permission for /usr/sbin/cron.d

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It is likely only 'root' login is allowed to manage the CRON world.